# FFmpeg: Invalid buffer size when streaming to Twitch

Tags: ffmpeg

I am streaming a 2560x1440 @ 24FPS to Twitch with this command:

```
ffmpeg \
>     -f rawvideo \
>     -vcodec rawvideo \
>     -s 2560x1440 \
>     -pix_fmt bgr24 \
>     -r "24" \
>     -i 20200818-074700.mp4 \
>     -f flv \
>     -vcodec libx264 \
>     -profile:v main \
>     -g 48 \
>     -keyint_min 24 \
>     -b:v 4500k \
>     -minrate 4500k \
>     -maxrate 4500k \
>     -pix_fmt yuv420p \
>     -preset ultrafast \
>     -tune zerolatency \
>     -threads 0 \
>     -bufsize 4500k \
>     rtmp://live-arn.twitch.tv/app/{KEY}
```

It fails with message `Invalid buffer size, packet size 9137374 < expected frame_size 11059200`. Given the error message, I have tried decreasing and increasing the `4500k` in all places of the command as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62944073/1965074) answer but it does not help.

Here is the full log

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.17-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[rawvideo @ 0xfb3120] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, rawvideo, from '20200818-074700.mp4':
  Duration: 00:00:02.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2118169 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[24] / 0x18524742), bgr24, 2560x1440, 2123366 kb/s, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 24 tbc
[libx264 @ 0xfbdfc0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0xfbdfc0] profile Constrained Baseline, level 5.0
[libx264 @ 0xfbdfc0] 264 - core 148 r2643 5c65704 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=22 lookahead_threads=16 sliced_threads=1 slices=22 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=48 keyint_min=24 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=0 rc=cbr mbtree=0 bitrate=4500 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=4500 vbv_bufsize=4500 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://live-arn.twitch.tv/app/{KEY}':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 2560x1440, q=-1--1, 4500 kb/s, 24 fps, 1k tbn, 24 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0xfbdfc0] VBV underflow (frame 0, -1827312 bits)
Truncating packet of size 11059200 to 9137375me=00:00:02.33 bitrate=6051.7kbits/s    
[rawvideo @ 0xfbca80] Invalid buffer size, packet size 9137374 < expected frame_size 11059200
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
[flv @ 0xfbd020] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0xfbd020] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
frame=   70 fps= 54 q=52.0 Lsize=    2029kB time=00:00:02.91 bitrate=5698.4kbits/s    
video:2026kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.152412%
[libx264 @ 0xfbdfc0] frame I:2     Avg QP:47.09  size:381468
[libx264 @ 0xfbdfc0] frame P:68    Avg QP:51.00  size: 19279
[libx264 @ 0xfbdfc0] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0xfbdfc0] mb P  I16..4: 14.1%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  2.7%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:83.2%
[libx264 @ 0xfbdfc0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 8.2% 94.6% 83.0% inter: 0.0% 3.2% 0.7%
[libx264 @ 0xfbdfc0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 87%  1% 12%  0%
[libx264 @ 0xfbdfc0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 98%  1%  2%  0%
[libx264 @ 0xfbdfc0] kb/s:5688.52
```

Comment: Why are you reading an MP4 as raw video?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I wanted to test with an mp4 but for production I will read frames via OpenCV into stdout and pipe stdout into this command with the mp4 file replaced with the minus sign. This doesn't work either at the moment so my question remains.

Comment: You have to drop all those input options since the MP4 doesn't contain any raw video. Replace them with a `-re` so it reads it at the native framerate to emulate a live stream.

Comment: Thanks for great feedback. You helped me work it out. This command worked for me and was inspired by this [link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites#Streamingafile): `ffmpeg -re -i 20200818-074700.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 3000k -maxrate 3000k -bufsize 6000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://live-arn.twitch.tv/app/{KEY}` Thanks! If you post as an answer I will accept.

Comment: Recommend you also update. FFmpeg 2.8 is ancient. [Download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

Comment: After updating the FFmpeg version you can also set the `-flvflags no_duration_filesize` to avoid failures when the video loops over.